# AWT with Grallvm

Tags: java, aws-lambda, quarkus, graalvm

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Add AWT Quarkus extension to enable Java2D/ImageIO. Additional system libraries such as `freetype' and `fontconfig' might be needed.
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:45)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1181)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:335)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:272)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:232)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:219)
at com.smartproof.lambda.service.CertificateGeneratorService.addOpenBadgeMetadata(CertificateGeneratorService.java:235)
at com.smartproof.lambda.service.CertificateGeneratorService.generateCertificate(CertificateGeneratorService.java:103)
at com.smartproof.lambda.service.CertificateGeneratorService_ClientProxy.generateCertificate(Unknown Source)
at com.smartproof.lambda.CertificateGeneratorLambda.handleRequest(CertificateGeneratorLambda.java:26)
at com.smartproof.lambda.CertificateGeneratorLambda.handleRequest(CertificateGeneratorLambda.java:17)
at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AmazonLambdaRecorder$1.processRequest(AmazonLambdaRecorder.java:170)
at io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.AbstractLambdaPollLoop$1.run(AbstractLambdaPollLoop.java:130)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:597)
at com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixJavaThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixJavaThreads.java:194)
```

We are build a native image and upload it to aws lambda at that time we got this type of issue.
Any suggestion?

Comment: awt? really? That's seriously going oldschool. have you read this part of the (partial) stacktrace you posted? => java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Add AWT Quarkus extension to enable Java2D/ImageIO. Additional system libraries such as `freetype' and `fontconfig' might be needed.

Comment: @Stultuske Yes i read that part but once i will added that and again build with graalvm then build fails.

Comment: Did you add the `AWT Quarkus extension` and still got the same failure afterwards?

Comment: Yes I am added quarkus-awt but still facing same issue

Comment: @ChristianWirth we can refere this issue

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/26682